# ORA-22992 without remote column on view create

Tags: sql, oracle, select, view, dblink

I'm getting **ORA-22992** error without any remote column reference.

Error: *ORA-22992
cannot use LOB locators selected from remote tables"
*Cause:    A remote LOB column cannot be referenced.
*Action:   Remove references to LOBs in remote tables.*

If I remove my else clause, it works fine. However the else clause doesn't have any remote table reference.

Code with error:

```
create or replace view v_myview as

select case 
        when exists (select count(routing_code), employee_id
                     from t_employee_logon
                     where routing_code = 'LOG-ON'
                     and employee_id = emp.id
                     group by employee_id
                     having count(routing_code) > 1)
          then 'Logado em mais de um servidor' 
        else (select control_number 
              from t_employee_logon 
              where employee_id = loc.location_id
              and wh_id = loc.wh_id
              and routing_code = 'LOG-ON'
              order by logon_start_date desc, logon_start_time desc
              fetch first 1 row only) 
      end as servidor
from t_location loc
inner join t_employee emp
  on loc.c1 = emp.id
  and loc.wh_id = emp.wh_id
inner join t_device@adv dev
  on dev.dev_name = emp.device
inner join t_device@adv dev2 
  on dev.link_device_id = dev2.device_id;
```

Code without error:

```
create or replace view v_myview as

select case 
        when exists (select count(routing_code), employee_id
                     from t_employee_logon
                     where routing_code = 'LOG-ON'
                     and employee_id = emp.id
                     group by employee_id
                     having count(routing_code) > 1)
          then 'Logado em mais de um servidor' 
        else 'Hello World'
      end as servidor
from t_location loc
inner join t_employee emp
  on loc.c1 = emp.id
  and loc.wh_id = emp.wh_id
inner join t_device@adv dev
  on dev.dev_name = emp.device
inner join t_device@adv dev2 
  on dev.link_device_id = dev2.device_id;
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

Could I suggest writing this as:

```
select (select (case when count(el.routing_code) > 1
                     then 'Logado em mais de um servidor'  
                     else cast(el.control_number as varchar2(255))
                end)
        from t_employee_logon el
        where el.routing_code = 'LOG-ON' and
              el.employee_id = emp.id
       ) as servidor
. . .
```

That is, put the `case` in the subquery so you don't have to run it twice.  Perhaps it will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was remove the case statement and make my select result in another select.

```
select (columns_my_select)
     , case_statement 
from (my_original_select_whithout_case);


select column1
     , column2
     , case 
    when exists (select count(routing_code), employee_id
                 from t_employee_logon
                 where routing_code = 'LOG-ON'
                 and employee_id = usuario
                 group by employee_id
                 having count(routing_code) > 1)
      then 'Logado em mais de um servidor' 
    else (select control_number 
          from t_employee_logon 
          where employee_id = usuario
          and wh_id = cd
          and routing_code = 'LOG-ON'
          order by logon_start_date desc, logon_start_time desc
          fetch first 1 row only) 
  end as servidor
from ( column1, column2 
  from t_location loc
  inner join t_employee emp
    on loc.c1 = emp.id
    and loc.wh_id = emp.wh_id
  inner join t_employee_logon empl
    on empl.employee_id = emp.id
    and empl.wh_id = emp.wh_id
  inner join t_device@adv dev
    on dev.dev_name = emp.device
  inner join t_device@adv dev2 
    on dev.link_device_id = dev2.device_id) user_info
group by usuario, cd, estoque_sto, estoque_hum, device, crf, controladora;
```